# Don't understand how they've calculated the transition probabilities

Tags: self-study, markov-process

> Suppose the weather condition classified as "sunny" (S) or "rainy" (R). Assume the condition on day $n + 1$ is dependent on the days $n$ and $n-1$ only. Work out the transition matrix from the table below.
>
> $$\pmatrix{\mathrm{Yesterday} & \mathrm{Today} & \mathrm{Tomorrow} \\ R & R & R \\ S & S & S \\S & R & R \\R & S & S \\}$$

So far, what I have done is said that if we let $X_n$ be the weather on day $n$, then $X_n$ isn't a discrete time markov chain as it doesn't satify the markov property. To turn it into a DTMC, lets say that $Y_n = (X_{n-1}, X_n)$. This is now a DTMC, with the state space $S = \{1, 2,3, 4\}$ where $1 = (R,R), 2 = (R, S), 3 = (S, R), 4 = (S, S)$. Now I want to work out the transition probabilites.

So first lets calculate $P_{11}$. So this is the probability of going from state 1 to state 1, i.e if it rains yesterday and today, what is the probability it will rain tomorrow. So I am working out

$$P\{Y_{n+1} = 1 | Y_n = 1\} = P\{X_{n} = R, X_{n+1} = R | X_{n-1} = R, X_{n} = R\}$$

I then said from here, using the law of total probability, we get

$$\frac{P\{X_{n} = R, X_{n+1} = R, X_{n-1} = R, X_{n} = R\}}{P\{X_{n-1} = R, X_{n} = R\}}$$

But in the answers, it says this line should read

> $$\frac{P\{X_{n} = R, X_{n+1} = R, X_{n-1} = R\}}{P\{X_{n-1} = R, X_{n} = R\}}$$

Then for some reason they go from here to

> $$P\{X_{n+1} = R | X_{n-1} = R, X_{n} = R\}$$

First, where does the $X_n$ go from the line above this, and secondly, how do they make the jump to the last line?

EDIT: Ok, this is the data in the table

> $$\begin{matrix} \mathrm{\underline{Yesterday}} & \mathrm{\underline{Today}} & \mathrm{\underline{Tomorrow}} & \mathrm{\underline{Prob.}} \\ R & R & R & 0.6 \\ S & S & S & 0.8 \\ S & R & R & 0.5 \\ R & S & S & 0.75 \end{matrix}$$

I tried to work out $P_{12}$ and got my formula to be $P(X_{n+1} = S | X_n = R, X_{n-1} R)$. How would I solve this using the table?

Also, in the answers, they say $P_{13} = 0$, why would this be?

Comment: Look closely. What is the difference between your formula and the first formula from the answers? Can you deduce why the numerators in both formulas actually express the same thing?

Comment: Because there's two $N_n = R$? and we only need to count it once?

Comment: Should $X_n = R$. Also, I figured out how they get the last bit. Am I correct in why the numerator changes though?

Comment: Exactly. Simply put, the probability that $X_n=R$ is of course equal to the probability that $X_n=R$ *and* $X_n=R$ (because we are simply saying the same thing twice). And the same holds true if we add additional conditionals to both expressions.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Ok, thanks for that. Can you help me with the bit in the edit?

Comment: For $P_{12}$: what do you already have in the table that corresponds to $X_n=R, X_{n-1}=R$? For $P_{13}$: what would a transition from state 1 to state 3 mean in terms of $X_{n+1}, X_n, X_{n-1}$.

Comment: For $P_{12}$ it would be the top line. OHhhhh! And because that top line says $X_{n+1} = R$ and I want $X_{n+1} = S$, I would do 1 - $P\{X_{n+1} = R\}$, right? For the third one, I was a bit lazy, let me work this out..

Comment: On the numerator, I end up getting $\{X_n = S, X_{n+1} = R, X_{n-1} = R, X_n = R\}$, so does this mean this can't happen as $X_n$ can't equal $S$ and $R$ at the same time?

Comment: ... and there you are!